# AngularJS Factories Being Shadowed in Controller

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, factory

I have laid out the object to be returned from the factory as so:

```
return {
    mapOptions: {
        center: {
            latitude: 0,
            longitude: 0
        },
        zoom: 5,
        mapType: 'r'
    }
```

Now in the controller, I am simply injecting it as a dependency:

```
MapController = function (MapStateFactory) {
    var self = this;

    //This is the direct approach
    self.MapStateFactory = MapStateFactory

    //This is the approach I want to use
    self.mapOptions = MapStateFactory.mapOptions;
}
Module.controller('MapController', ['MapStateFactory', MapController]);
```

In the view, I am using some of the options returned to populate some data-attributes on a directive:

```
//MapController as map
//Direct approach
<data-custom-directive data-map-options="map.MapStateFactory.mapOptions"/>

//Approach I want to take
<data-custom-directive data-map-options="map.mapOptions"/>
```

Now both seem to work, but as I have found with my short time with AngularJS, either, both or neither of these might actually be shadowing and not actually referencing the factory, so when I update the factory they may not change.

Which approach should I undertake? Is there any issue at all in simply injecting the factory, and then addressing the factory straight in the view by setting a `self.FactoryNameReference` and using that?

Edit: The main reason I want to take the overly long way around, is because I don't want to setup a weird naming dependency (if `MapStateFactory` was to change in the future to a new name, you would have a lot of views to update as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `MapStateFactory` doesn't reassign `mapOptions` property, this

```
<data-custom-directive data-map-options="mapOptions"/>
```

is ok. If `MapStateFactory.mapOptions = { ... }` is done anywhere *after* `mapOptions` was bound to scope, they are referring to different objects. If a new object needs to assigned to mapOptions, `angular.copy({ ... }, MapStateFactory.mapOptions);` should be used instead.

> Edit: The main reason I want to take the overly long way around, is
>   because I don't want to setup a weird naming dependency (if
>   MapStateFactory was to change in the future to a new name, you would
>   have a lot of views to update as well)

It doesn't look like a valid argument for overcomplication. You can make a [facade](https://carldanley.com/js-facade-pattern/) service for `MapStateFactory`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "reassign". What would that look like? I'll take a look at the facade service, thanks.

Comment: So if for instance I had a variable in that factory, that was called `foo`, if i use `self.foo = Factory.foo` and then further into the application call something that changes the `foo` in the factory, will it be reflected with both use cases or is there one that wouldn't work?

Comment: It will work if foo is object/array, and you change foo's properties.